# extension get content before page load

Tags: firefox-addon, addeventlistener

I want to develop a extension to prevent some events in loaded page
I write this code but it loads after page loaded completely.
i want to prevent body and window click,mouse up,mouse down events because some sites use them listeners to run popup windows.I want to register a listener for them and prevent running popup codes.
here is my try but need to register listener before document complete

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { bgnmyExtension.init(); }, false);
var bgnmyExtension = {
    init: function() {
    var bgnappcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser
    if(bgnappcontent)
      bgnappcontent.addEventListener("load", bgnmyExtension.onPageLoad, true);
    var bgnmessagepane = document.getElementById("messagepane"); // mail
    if(bgnmessagepane)
      bgnmessagepane.addEventListener("load", function() { bgnmyExtension.onPageLoad(); }, true);
  },

  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {

      var bgmyfn=setInterval(function(){MyPopupBlocker()},1);
var bgndoc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered "onload" event



function MyPopupBlocker(){
          window.onclick=null;
          bgndoc.onclick=null;
          window.onmousedown=null;
          bgndoc.onmousedown=null;
          window.onmouseup=null;
          bgndoc.onmouseup=null
}
 if (!bgndoc.addEventListener) 
    bgndoc.attachEvent('onclick',MyPopupBlocker,true);
else
    bgndoc.addEventListener('click',MyPopupBlocker,true);

function bgPreloadExit(){if(bgbgPreload)bgPreload(true)};
function btmainfn(){
    var checkbticon=bgndoc.getElementById("bgnmyID");
    if(checkbticon==null && window==window.top){
        bgndoc.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin","<div align='left' style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:10000' id='bgnmyID'><a href='http://*****'><img src='http://*****/images/My.jpg'></a></div>");
        setTimeout(function(){var e=document.getElementById("bgnmyID");e.parentNode.removeChild(e)},3000);
        } else {
            clearInterval(checkbtmain)}
}
var checkbtmain=setInterval(function(){btmainfn()},500);

} 
}
```

EDIT:

i use this code now but it doesn't add my script to my current document:

```
init();
 var intval;
 var intvalhead;
function init(){
    intval = setInterval ( "checkForElement()", 200 );
}
function checkForHead(){
    if (typeof document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] != 'undefined'){
        clearInterval(intvalhead);
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.text = "function stopFunction(e){e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();}document.addEventListener( 'click', stopFunction, false );document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', stopFunction, false );      document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', stopFunction, false );      window.addEventListener( 'click', stopFunction, false );        window.addEventListener( 'mouseup', stopFunction, false );      window.addEventListener( 'mousedown', stopFunction, false );";
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

}
function checkForElement(){
    console.log("bbb");
    if (document.getElementById('appcontent') != 'undefined'){
        clearInterval(intval);
        var appcontent = window.document.getElementById("appcontent");
        intvalhead = setInterval ( "checkForHead()", 200 );
    }
}
```

before it i used this code :

```
function init(){
    intval = setInterval ( "checkForElement()", 200 );
}
function disable(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function checkForElement(){
    console.log("bbb");
    if (document.getElementById('appcontent') != 'undefined'){
        clearInterval(intval);
        var appcontent = window.document.getElementById("appcontent");
        window.document.addEventListener("click", disable, false);
        window.document.addEventListener("mouseup", disable, false);
        window.document.addEventListener("mousedown", disable, false);
        document.addEventListener("click", disable, false);
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", disable, false);
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", disable, false);
    }
}
```

but it prevent all clicks,i want to prevent current doucment,but i thing window and document in this case is whole of browser.
i have some code like this to get current document,but i want it begore load completed:

```
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {

var bgndoc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered "onload" event
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how early you need to run the script.

If you need to run the code before the requests are made, then you can use [HTTP Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#HTTP_Observers).

If you need to run the code before page scripts are run, then you can use [beforescriptexecute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforescriptexecute).

You can also add 'click' event listeners to the nodes in question and prevent their normal action with [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) & [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

**Update:**
Further to the comments bellow, here is an example of how it can be done (tested with a GreaseMonkey script). It is made to remove multiple scripts.

```
// listening for the script execution
document.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', removeJS, false);

function removeJS(e) {

  var uri = e.target.src;
  if(!uri) { return; } // end execution if not external script

  switch (true) {

    case uri.indexOf('shoptou.js') !== -1:
    // case uri.indexOf('abcd.com') !== -1: // in case you need to remove other scripts
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log('removed ' + uri); // removed http://www.parsnaz.ir/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/?f=shoptou.js&m=1447510600
      break;
  }
}
```

If that is the only script you need to remove, you can simplify the above function:

```
function removeJS(e) {

  var uri = e.target.src;
  if(uri && uri.indexOf('shoptou.js') !== -1 ) { 

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('removed ' + uri); // removed http://www.parsnaz.ir/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/?f=shoptou.js&m=1447510600 
  }
}
```

In case of `on*` attributes, you can simply remove them with `removeAttribute()`.
In case of registered listeners, you can use `Event.preventDefault()` & `Event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: thnks,i used your suggested functions and events but still have problem to prevent events in current loading page.

Comment: @mojtabadddd There are a mixture of content/page scope functions and browser scope functions. Please explain what exactly you are trying to do with simple code example as going through a long code makes it more complected.

Comment: some site add a event listener to document and window to run popup window,current Popup Blockers could not prevent them,so i want to load a script to prevent popups,i want just document and window listeners remove or ovveride in all pages.

Comment: @mojtabadddd .. can you give an example of such page?

Comment: surely,http://www.parsnaz.ir/ is a example,just click on page and popup runs,it use this script i its source to runs popup: view-source:http://www.parsnaz.ir/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/?f=shoptou.js&m=1447510600

Comment: some of sites use addlistener and some others use document.onclick=LoadStandardPop same as my example,is that possible to prevent these type of popups?if i register listener for document and windows clicks and disable bubbles,maybe button and other elements clicks don't work correctly?and how to do my plan?

Comment: Wow very cool stuff eros! I didn't know of this `beforescriptexecute`!

Comment: @mojtabadddd .. I made a sample code for you that you can work on and updated my above reply.

Comment: @erosman thanks,but every site use different url,maybe it use inline js instead external js files, i think solution is to found a way to remove listeners or override them

Comment: @mojtabadddd ... Of course, that is why I asked for an example as there isn't a single solution that suits all.

Comment: @erosman Is there a solution to remove all on click listener that listen for document and window?

Comment: @mojtabadddd .. yes ... there are many ways ... give me an example to work something out

Comment: @erosman Thanks,here is another site http://www.khandefun.ir/, i think it open popup with this script www.khandefun.ir/js/site.js there are several ways to open popup window? here is another example www.tafrihi.com/ that use addlistener, i think is better to find a way to prevent opening window in all sites and have a white list.whats your opinion?

Comment: @mojtabadddd .. best way is to use NoScript to block the JS. The second site is blocked by ESET for bad JS content. The first site is similar to one I wrote the code before. It is difficult to find a solution that works for all sites.

Comment: @erosman i found new solution,i used beforescriptexecute and get text of script that wants to run,then if it include addlistener and others block it,problem is beforescriptexecute do not detect scripts that runs on external js files